# How to detect a loader on a page with hidden class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver 2.53.1 with java and firefox 45.0.1 and try to detect a loader on page with hidden class, but I get this error message:

> The given selector //[@class='se-pre-con hidden-xs hidden-sm'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
>   InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //[@class='se-pre-con hidden-xs hidden-sm'] because of the following error:
>   SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

This is the class I want to detect:

```
<div class="se-pre-con hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div>
```

Comment: What code are you using to achieve this output? It's hard to fix syntax errors if we can't see the syntax... Try showing a minimal, complete and verifyable example.

Comment: The error message tells you what the problem is. Your selector is invalid. Take some time to read some XPath (or preferably CSS selector) tutorials and update your selector.

Answer (score 2):

Your xpath is invalid. After "//" you need to add the element you are selecting or a wildcard (*) for every element. So the correct xpath would be `//div[@class='se-pre-con hidden-xs hidden-sm']` or `//*[@class='se-pre-con hidden-xs hidden-sm']`.

You can use WebDriverWait to ignore [StaleElementReferenceException](http://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp) and wait for the element to be visible:

```
By elementSelector = By.xpath("//div[@class='se-pre-con hidden-xs hidden-sm']");
WebElement matchingElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(elementSelector));
```

Comment: I try your example and found new error...."Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
" Please help to resolve it